# How is this a “draw by three-fold repetition”?

Tags: draw, threefold-repetition, claim-draw

How is this a **draw by three-fold repetition**? Following my last move, the app notified me of a draw by three-fold repetition.

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
1.Nf3 Nc6 2.Nc3 h6 3.d3 Nd4 4.Qd2 a6 5.Qe3 Nf6 6.Qxd4 Rb8 7.Qh4 d5 8.Qd4 a5 9.Qxd5 Rh7 10.Qxa5 Qd6 11.Qd5 e5 12.Qxd6 Rh8 13.Qxe5+ Kd8 14.Qd5+ Bd7 15.Qf5 h5 16.Qxh5 Rh6 17.Qxh6 Ng4 18.Qh4+ Kc8 19.Qxg4 Be7 20.Qxg7 Be6 21.Qxf7 Bb4 22.Qxe6+ Kd8 23.Qc4 Bf8 24.Qf4 Ke7 25.Qxf8+ Kd7 26.Qxb8 Ke7 27.Qxb7 Kf6 28.Qxc7 Kg6 29.Qc4 Kg7 30.Ng1 Kf8 31.Nb1 Kg7 32.Qc3+ Kg6 33.Qd2 Kf6 34.Qd1 Kf5 35.Qd2 Kg4 36.Qe3 Kh5 37.d4 Kg6 38.c4 Kf7 39.b4 Kg8 40.a4 Kf8 41.Qa3 Ke8 42.e4 Kd7 43.Qf3 Kc8 44.Qf5+ Kb7 45.f4 Kc7 46.g4 Kb8 47.h4 Kc7 48.a5 Kc6 49.a6 Kd6 50.a7 Kc7 51.a8=R Kb6 52.R8a4 Kb7 53.b5 Kb8 54.b6 Kb7 55.Qd5+ Kb8 56.b7 Kc7 57.Qe5+ Kd7 58.b8=R Kc6 59.Rbb4 Kd7 60.Qb5+ Kd6 61.c5+ Ke7 62.c6 Kf7 63.c7 Kf8 64.c8=R+ Ke7 65.Rcc4 Kd8 66.d5 Ke7 67.d6+ Kf8 68.d7 Kg7 69.d8=R Kg6 70.Rdd4 Kh6 71.Qd5 Kh7 72.e5 Kg7 73.e6 Kh6 74.e7 Kh7 75.e8=R Kh6 76.Ree4 Kg6 77.f5+ Kg7 78.f6+ Kh8 79.f7 Kg7 80.f8=R Kg6 81.Rff4 Kh7 82.Qh5+ Kg8 83.Rf3 Kg7 84.Rfh3 Kg8 85.Ree3 Kf8 86.Re2 Kg8 87.Reh2 Kg7 88.Rd1 Kf8 89.Bf4 Ke7 90.Rcc3 Kf6 91.Rcf3 Ke6 92.Rbb2 Ke7 93.Rbg2 Ke6 94.Rgg3 Ke7 95.R4a2 Ke6 96.Rag2 Kf6 97.g5+ Kf5 98.g6+ Kf6 99.g7 Ke7 100.g8=R Kf6 101.Rga8 Ke7 102.R8a2 Kf6 103.Raf2 Ke7 104.Qg5+ Kf7 105.h5 Ke6 106.h6 Kf7 107.h7 Ke6 108.h8=R Kf7 109.Be5+ Ke6 110.Qg4+ Kxe5 111.Qh4 Ke6 112.Rb8 Ke5 113.Rbb2 Ke6 114.Rdd2 Ke5 115.Rde2+ Kd6 116.Rbd2+ Kc6 117.Rdd3 Kb7 118.Rde3 Kc8 119.Rf4 Kb8 120.Nf3 Kb7 121.Nd4 Kc8 122.R4f3 Kb8 123.Re4 Kb7 124.R2e3 Kb6 125.Bc4 Kc7 126.Ba6 Kb8 127.Bb7 Kc7 128.Bd5 Kb8 129.O-O Kc7 130.Na3 Kd6 131.Nab5+ Kd7 132.Rae1 Kc8 133.R4e3 Kb8 134.Na3 Kc8 135.Nb1 Kc7 136.Na3 Kd6 137.Nb1 Kc5 138.Nc2 Kxd5 139.Nca3 Kc5 140.Nc4 Kc6 141.Ne5+ Kb6 142.Nd7+ Kb5 143.Nc5 Kxc5 144.Na3 Kb6 145.Nb5 Ka5 146.Na7 Ka6 147.Rd4 Kb7 148.Rde4 Ka8 149.Ref4 Kb7 150.Rfg4 Kb6 151.Nc6 Kc7 152.Na7 Kb7 153.Nb5 Kb8 154.Nd6 Ka7 155.Nb5+ Kb8 156.Nc7 Kc8 157.Na8 Kb7 158.Nc7 Kb6 159.Nd5+ Kb7 160.Nb6 Kc6 161.Nc8 Kb7 162.Ne7 Kb8 163.Nc8 Kxc8 164.Qd8+ Kxd8 165.Kh1 Kd7 166.Ra1 Kd8 167.Ree1 Kc7 168.Reb1 Kc6 169.Ree1 Kd6 170.Rec1 Ke6 171.Rff1 Kd6 172.Rfd1+ Ke7 173.Rff1 Ke6 174.Rfe1+ Kf6 175.Rgg1 Kf5 176.R3g2 Kf6 177.Rga4 Kf5 178.Rha3 Kf6 179.Rga2 Kf7 180.Rhb2 Kf6 181.Kh2 Kf5 182.Kh3 Kf6 183.Kh4 Kf5 184.Kg3 Kf6 185.Kf4 Kf7 186.Ke4 Ke7 187.Kd5+ Kd8 188.Rh2 Kd7 189.Rh1 Kd8 190.Rf2 Kd7 191.Rff1 Kd8 192.Rah3 Kd7 193.Rhe3 Kd8 194.R4a3 Kd7 195.Rad3 Kd8 196.Re4 Kd7 197.Rd4 Kd8 198.Kc5+ Kc8 199.Kd5+ Kd7 200.Ke5+ Ke7 201.Kf5+ Kf8 202.Kg5+ Kg7 203.Kh5+ Kh8 204.Kg5+ Kg7 205.Kf5+ Kf8 206.Ke5+ Ke7 207.Kd5+ Kd8 208.Kc5+ Kc8 209.Kb5+ Kb8 210.Ka5+ Ka8 211.Kb5+ Kb7 212.Kc5+ Kc7 213.Kd5+ Kd8 214.Ke5+
```

Comment: I edited move 133, but you still have an error at move 169.

Answer (score 4):

FIDE rules, 5.1:

> d. The game may be drawn if any identical position is about to appear or has appeared on the chessboard at least three times. (See Article 9.2)

FIDE rules, 9.2:

> The  game  is  drawn  upon  a  correct  claim  by  the  player  having  the  move,  when  the  same  position, for at least the third time ***(not necessarily by a repetition of moves)***: 
>   ...

The emphasis is mine, and that's what happened here. The position was repeated 3 times, but the moves weren't. However,  that is still a draw.

Answer (score 3):

Your diagram does not work on my computer.  Draw by repetition is when a player repeats the SAME *POSITION* 3 times.
 They do not have to repeat immediately during only three moves.

Same means same person on move, nothing different like castling or pawn moves or captures.   Position can take several moves to come back to the same one and the in between positions do not matter.

I am not going to play over that game on my physical board to find it but if the computer said so then there were three repetitions.

Look at the position after your moves 200 206 and 214 and see if the position is not the same with the same person having moved.